# How to fix tia portal v13 error installation?

Tags: installation, automation, siemens, tia-portal, simatic-net

I've been trying to install tia v13 a while a go and this error is showing up everytime(fatal error in simatic net components sntieno.dll), I reinstalled it and reinitialized my PC hoping this error will disappear but it seems that nothing works
Please help me out I need it for my studies
The resume was showing this message " error seconworker::executeseconwork(): - secon call has been finished with errors "
[[here is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eCEBe.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YgVXH.jpg)

I tried to reinstall it but the error occured
Also tried to install sntieno.dll and include it in the doc

Comment: https://support.industry.siemens.com/forum/ch/en/posts/siem-isotrans-step7-installation-fatal-error-pc-with-windows-10/159764, you are using maybe windows 10 and it is not supported, windows 10 is supported with tia v 14